# How to specify interaction beetween button click event handlers?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, button, eventhandler

In the program, by clicking button2, is created a table and imlemented data insertion. Also created textbox and login button, which is used for reading data from this textbox. When the login button is pressed, next actions should happen:

- MessageBox should display some text;
- login.Text should be changed;
- table, which was created by clicking button2 should be deleted.

I dont know actually how to get access from login.click event handler to table in button2. I guess it should be done somehow by using EventArgs, but i dont understand how. Also I thought about creating some variable outside button2 handler scope, and use it later, but I guess its a bad practise.
Please,tell me how to solve this, or maybe its just wrong decision to create windows forms components such a way? if it`s so, then how to?) here is my code:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Hide();
        label2.Hide();
        textBox1.Hide();
        textBox2.Hide();
        button2.Hide();

        int user_count = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        int file_count = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        DataGridView T = new DataGridView();
        T.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        T.AutoResizeColumns();
        T.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        T.ColumnCount = file_count + 1;
        T.RowCount = user_count + 1;

        Controls.Add(T);

        Controller_cs c = new Controller_cs(user_count, file_count);


        for(int i = 1; i < T.RowCount; i++)
        {
           T.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = c.user_name_insertion(i-1);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < T.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            T.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value = c.file_name_insertion(i - 1);
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < T.RowCount;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j < T.ColumnCount;j++)
            {
                T.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = c.rigts_insertion(j-1,i-1); 
            }
        }

        Label l = new Label();
        l.Text = "Name";
        l.Left = 20;
        l.Top = 180;
        Controls.Add(l);

        TextBox username = new TextBox();
        username.Left = 20;
        username.Top = 210;
        Controls.Add(username);

        Button login = new Button();
        login.Text = "Enter";
        login.Left = 130;
        login.Top = 175;

        login.Click += login_handler;
        Controls.Add(login);
    }

    private void login_handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        if (b.Text == "Enter")
        {
            b.Text = "Exit";
            MessageBox.Show("Enter is done");
        }
        else
        {
            b.Text = "Enter";
            MessageBox.Show("Quit is done");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have constant values for all controls(size, position and even text). Create all controls in the designer and use `.Visible` property to hide and show them. Or put related controls to the same `GroupBox` for example, then you need change visibility only for group control.

Comment: if I willl create them in designer i will have access to them from anywhere, but i want to know how to access them when I create Controls by code. or its just bad practise to create and assign Controlls in some button event handler? this is the question i couldnt clerify

Comment: After you create controls in `button_click` eventhandler and add them to the `Controls` collection by `Controls.Add(someNewControl)`, you will have access to them from anywhere of your form through `Controls` collection.

Comment: I havent hear about Controls collection before. could you just give me example how access the exact controll? any label/textbox etc. from button2_click event handler.

Comment: [Control.Controls Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If you need add controls to form directly is necessary indicate to your control belonging to form adding "this" prefix, example: "this.Controls.Add(textBox);" in the case you need add the control to other container (GroupBox or any other) is necessary add the control to container, example: "this.groupBox.Controls.Add(textBox);" a resource of these 
[Adding Controls to Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984255(v=vs.71).aspx)